# regex that matches any positive or negative numeric value but no characters or mixed strings

Tags: regex, numbers

I haven't used regular expressions till now, but I need a regex that matches a string representing a positive or negative numeric value like

234

-8

3.346

-564.4

It should NOT match any text or mixtures of characters (<>#?_...), numbers and text like

abc

.-.

<11.45

amount111.43

345.654.33

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please *read* the FAQ. We will help with specific questions - we are not here to do your task for you in its entirety. Post some code, show us what you've tried, and if you need help, we're here.

Comment: Just my two cents: This question could have been better worded but I understood exactly what the OP wanted and the question has a valid solution. So why the down votes?

Answer (score 13):

This should do it:

```
^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

`^` start of string

`-?` minus sign one or zero times

`\d+` digits, one or more

`(\.\d+)?` a dot following by one or more digits, this whole block one or zero times

`$` end of string

Also take note of Utkanos comment for your next question on SO :)

Comment: Thx a lot, it works perfectly. 

I had tried '^[+-]?\d*\.?,?\d+$' but with that I missed some character/number combinations

Comment: I tried this regex. It is not working for me. I am trying to suppress the alpha characters using this regex but failed to achieve it.

Comment: I achieved it by following regex 
[^-?0-9\\.(0-9?)].

Comment: @TusharBanne that regex is not very logical, compare your regex (https://regexper.com/#%5B%5E-%3F0-9%5C%5C.(0-9%3F)%5D) with mine (https://regexper.com/#%5E-%3F%5Cd%2B(%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F%24)